# Copy image to another folder

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, system.io.file

I am using Xamaring forms and I am trying to copy selected image path to another location on smartphone but is not working.
Any ideas why and how to fix it?

```
  private async Task btn_AddImg_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                Error.IsVisible = true;
                Error.Text = file.FilePath;

                var dirToCreate = Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, "WightLossPersonal");
                if (!Directory.Exists(dirToCreate))
                {

                    var x= Directory.CreateDirectory(dirToCreate);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(file.FilePath, dirToCreate, true);

                }
                else
                {
                   System.IO.File.Copy(file.FilePath, dirToCreate, true);
                }

            }
        }
```

In my Manifest I got permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Error Message :

"/data/user/0/com.companyname.WightLoss/files/WightLossPersonal is a directory"

[image]

Comment: `and I am getting even an error message` How about sharing that message?

Comment: sorry i corrected it. I am not getting even an error message.

Comment: Use try/catch and see what exception is thrown.  What is so hard to try.

Comment: Good idea. I updated my question

Comment: post it as text...

Comment: i added it on my updated question......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your main issue is you didn't pass the file name in the new dir.
So it's like you are trying to copy the dir itself, not the file !

Basically you have to combine the file name with the dir
then pass it to Copy() method.

```
string destFolder = Path.Combine(dirToCreate, file.Name);
System.IO.File.Copy(file.FilePath, destFolder , true);
```

but let's make the code more clean. And I'll comment the code for better understanding.

```
private async Task btn_AddImg_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                Error.IsVisible = true;
                Error.Text = file.FilePath;

                var dirToCreate = Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, "WightLossPersonal");
                if (!Directory.Exists(dirToCreate))
                {
                      Directory.CreateDirectory(dirToCreate);
                   // var x= Directory.CreateDirectory(dirToCreate); // don't need that variable x here since you don't want to use it later
                    //System.IO.File.Copy(file.FilePath, dirToCreate, true); No need here, will copy it in all ways down .

                }
                //else   // you don't need else, copy the file when finishing the check.
                //{

                  // Make a new path to compine the dir and the fileName
                   string destFolder = Path.Combine(dirToCreate, file.Name);
                   System.IO.File.Copy(file.FilePath, destFolder , true);
                //}

            }


  }
```

Comment: Very clean code.  I update my code with yours but now i am getting : "Access to the path \"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180615_073317.jpg\" or \"/data/user/0/com.companyname.WightLoss/files/WightLossPersonal/IMG_20180615_073317.jpg\" is denied."

Comment: Well,  now it's a permission issue, I think you are trying to copy the file into non- external storage so u need the right permission to do that

Comment: I have in my manifest : permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
    permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: these permissions for the external storage, would you check if this path is in the external storage ? `data/user/0/com.companyname.WightLoss/files/WightLossPersonal/`

Comment: try replacing the path with this one : `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
   System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` I think this will get your application folder.

Comment: I found the problem. I had to go manually on phone settings permission on the app and enable it. But why this? I enable it in my manifest. Should be enable auto?

Comment: I think it's the way you are trying to get your app path. Did you try with my previous comment ? I'm not familiar with xamarin sorry

Comment: Yes. Still the same error. I have to go manually and allow application permission every time.

Comment: If you are targeting Marshmallow and above, then you have to consider the runtime permissions.